# MYSQL table calendar and right Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I fill gaps between rows? Im using table calendar but my query does not seem to be correct. The result is not showing the gaps..

```
SELECT calendar.datefield, t2.*
    FROM store_relation t1,store t3, store_product t2
            RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(t2.created) = calendar.datefield)
            WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2012-07-15') and ('2012-07-20'))
    AND t1.id_store_a = 1
    AND t1.id_store_b = t2.id_store
    AND t3.id = t2.id_store
    AND t2.id_product = 11
    ORDER By t2.price
```

Result:

```
datefield   |   id_product   |   id_store   |   created
2012-07-15      1                1              2012-07-15
2012-07-18      1                1              2012-07-18
2012-07-20      1                1              2012-07-20
2012-07-20      1                1              2012-07-20
```

I was waiting for the result

```
datefield   |   id_product   |   id_store   |   created
2012-07-15      1                1              2012-07-15
2012-07-16      null             null           null
2012-07-17      null             null           null
2012-07-18      1                1              2012-07-18
2012-07-19      null             null           null
2012-07-20      1                1              2012-07-20
2012-07-20      1                1              2012-07-20
```

Comment: @MohamedNuur `RIGHT JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` are the same thing

Comment: Does your calendar table have all dates in in?

Comment: generating the missing numbers in a sequence is a common problem.  You can see my usual solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020667/how-to-get-all-dates-in-a-month/11021035#11021035

Comment: The answers below are great.  You should be writing your SQL fully using proper JOIN syntax, which means using the ON clause instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN and you are filtering on tables that are optionally included, the `WHERE` clause will leave those records out.  You need to include a condition that allows for the left part of the `RIGHT JOIN` being missing:

```
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2012-07-15') and ('2012-07-20'))
AND
(
   (t1.id_store_a = 1
   AND t1.id_store_b = t2.id_store
   AND t3.id = t2.id_store
   AND t2.id_product = 11)
   OR
   (t2.id_product is NULL)
)
```

For example, if you look at your expected output, the value of `id_product` is null, but you are filtering for `t2.id_product = 11`.  So the `null` records are never going to match `11`, and that's why they are being left out.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing some of the columns on the left side in your `WHERE` clause. Try explicitly adding an `OR NULL` condition. For example:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield, t2.*
FROM store_relation t1,store t3, store_product t2
        RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(t2.created) = calendar.datefield)
        WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2012-07-15') and ('2012-07-20'))
AND ((t1.id_store_a = 1
        AND t1.id_store_b = t2.id_store
        AND t3.id = t2.id_store
        AND t2.id_product = 11)
    OR (t1.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL AND t3.id IS NULL))
ORDER By t2.price
```

You'll have to decide which table(s) you want to allow to be null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it...Thank you for giving me new ideas

```
SELECT calendar.datefield as DATE, t2.*
FROM store_relation t1,store t3, store_product t2
    RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(t2.created) = calendar.datefield)
    WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2012-07-15') and ('2012-07-27'))
AND ((t1.id_store_a = 1
    AND t1.id_store_b = t2.id_store
    AND t3.id = t2.id_store
    AND t2.id_product = 11)
OR (t2.id_product IS NULL))
GROUP BY DATE
```